# How do I identify the database for a website in phpMyAdmin

Tags: database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

In my hosting account I have multiple databases for my sites and because I didn't know better at that time I let the install wizard use the default name so now I have 12 databases all with names `user_wrdp1` `user_wrdp2` ... `user_wrdp12`.

Now I need to export the db for one of my websites but I don't know how to identify it.

Please someone help me out

Answer (score 5):

You can go to your websites Filemanager or login to the FTP. Find the `wp-config.php` file, In that file, you will find the database name for that website like this

`define('DB_NAME', 'user_wrdp1');`

Also you can use phpmyadmin to browse that database. under wp_options table you can see the website url.

[image]

*** database prefix can be something other than `wp_` in some websites.

Regards

Comment: To be more specific - "websites ftp" - you can either visit your site via your FTP client, and there is a directory which contains your wordpress install.  OR, you can (often) use the cPanel / control panel "FTP" or "File Manager" to browser to the right location.